# Keras' Evaluate function training model on test set

Tags: neural-network, keras

I've been using Keras to do some timeseries predictive neural nets.
One thing that's had me staggered is how I was getting an almost 99% accuracy rate on very very noisy and uncorrelated data (I was looking for accuracy of around 50% to be good!)...

What I've now found, is that after I trained my model on the training set, I was casually running `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)` before then running a manual backtest on the data. The manual backtest on x_test and comparing it to the error in y_test then showed almost perfect accuracy...

Am I then correct in assuming that Keras when using the `evaluate()` function in Keras the original model is actually updated with the testing data as well? This seems a bit strange and counterintuitive to me?

Comment: Could you provide minimal working example? 99% accuracy on small training dataset suggests overfitting. How big is your dataset? Additionally [evaluate](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods) does not have any reported side effects, so it should not update your model (that would be bad design anyway if it did).

Answer (score 1):

Keras doesn't update your model with testing data. 
It might be that your labels have been provided wrong in the test data, check the model.predict_classes() to get the output of your classes and crosscheck them with your actual output manually by picking random subset.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between accuracy and validation accuracy. Add in a term "validation_split = .2" into the model.fit statement and see if the validation accuracy is still 99%. If you are dealing with truly uncorrelated data and are getting 99% accuracy then you are over fitting the dataset and need more Ys in your sample as compared to the number of X variables.